# angularjs: dynamic key:value pair as arguments to a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a key value pair which is dynamic.

```
myObj = { 
    category1: ["a","b","c"], 
    category2: ["a","d","e"],
    category3: ["a","f","g"],
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

I need to get intersection value as "a". For that I'm using underscore js's
`_.intersection()`  function

Depending on dynamic categories, I need to pass dynamic arguments to `_.intersection()`

like

```
_.intersection(myObj[category1], myObj[category2], ..., ..., myObj[categoryN]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
_.intersection.apply(_, Object.values(myObj));
```